# jquery window width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[in this demo](http://firatabak.com/test/anasayfa.html) if you click inputs in dark blue area (NUMARANI GONDER) you gonna see nothing happend but if you click on responsive mode (less than 768px) u gonna see modal has been opening it's okey this is the thing that I want but if u click again on dekstop mode black element has been opening

I'm using bootstrap modal and my JS Codes

```
 var $window = $(window),
     $nogonder = $('.add-modal');
     $(window).on('resize', function () {
        if ($window.width() < 768) {
          $nogonder.on("click",function(){
            $("#parallaxPopup").modal('show');
          })

       }else{
        $("#parallaxPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#rezervasyonPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#popupCheckin").modal('hide');
       };
     });
```

Comment: I don't see a modal in either mode. Also, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: on sidebar dark blue are there are two input if you clik on responsive you are gonna see modal

Comment: You didn't mention the inputs. Please *edit your question* to clarify.

Comment: I added now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause:

Notice that it only happens if hit the case where the window is < 768 and then you resize it to be larger. If you start large it is fine.

This is because you are not unbinding the event.

## Solution:

```
 var $window = $(window),
     $nogonder = $('.add-modal');
     $(window).on('resize', function () {
        if ($window.width() < 768) {
          $nogonder.on("click",function(){
            $("#parallaxPopup").modal('show');
          })

       }else{
        $nogonder.off("click");
        $("#parallaxPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#rezervasyonPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#popupCheckin").modal('hide');
       };
     });
```

Comment: hi again, it works very well but on iphone and another mobile devices it doesn't works for example; http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://www.firatabak.com/test/otel-listeleme.html

Comment: if I remove just window.resize it works on mobile but not working on dekstop responsive

Comment: You are probably triggering a resize on desktop but not on mobile. Changing `'resize'` to `'load resize'` will probably fix the problem, but I think you should learn some more about jQuery so you can avoid these problems in the first place. I would start with https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery

Comment: like this ?
  $(window).on("load",function(){
            var $window = $(window),
             $nogonder = $('.add-modal');
        if ($window.width() < 768) {
          $nogonder.on("click",function(){
            $("#parallaxPopup").modal('show');
          })

       }else{
        $nogonder.off("click");
        $("#parallaxPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#rezervasyonPopup").modal('hide');
        $("#popupCheckin").modal('hide');
       };
    })